# DBMS_SCHEDULER Calendaring Syntax

Tags: oracle, syntax, scheduler

I am new to `DBMS_SCHEDULER` and, after reading Oracle's documentation, am wondering if anyone could check my syntax for the repeat interval?

**Daily, at 3am**

```
FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=3
```

**Sundays, at 3am**

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SUN;BYHOUR=3
```

**Beginning of the Month, at 3am**

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1;BYHOUR=3
```

**Quarterly (Beginning of Jan, Apr, Jul, Oct), at 3am**

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0101,0401,0701,1001;BYHOUR=3
```

**Annually, on 1st Aug, at 3am**

```
FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0801;BYHOUR=3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intervals are vague, and thus may not start when you expect.

e.g lets say you ran `dbms_scheduler.create_job`  at `16:09:12`. your repeat interval of `FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=3` would mean that the job would start at `03:09:12` the next day. So in effect you got what you asked for.

if you want the job to start at 3am sharp, then

```
freq=DAILY;byhour=3; byminute=0; bysecond=0;
```

the same goes for all of your examples. whilst what you have is ok, they are only accurate to the hour and Oracle will pick the minute and second from the submission time.